# REST API Client in Tomcat returning ConnectionTimedOut

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jakarta-ee

In the client environment tomcat is running as a service with logon account as Local System Account. I have deployed a java based REST API client application in that tomcat. Every time the client is running its not able to set up connection with the destination.

In the client environment tomcat is running as a service with logon account as Local System Account. I have deployed a java based REST API client application in that tomcat. Every time the client is running its not able to set up connection with the destination.

There is absolutely no issue with the destination endpoint and the java code, as in other environments, that client is running fine in the tomcat.

Error that we are seeing is -- ConnectionTimeOut.

Account that the tomcat is running under in the client environment is -- Local System Account.

This is a huge road blocker and if anybody can provide guidance will be extremely helpful.

Error that we are seeing is -- ConnectionTimeOut.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely it might be firewall issue. Your client is not able to connect to server, where your  service is running. You need to ping from client machine to server where service is running. That will tells you whether Connectivity established or not.